# How to use a third party theme in a server side blazor app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I am trying to install a third party theme on a new server sided blazor app.
https://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin/

In order to get it working properly, I need to load the Javascript from the theme after I have got the rendered page because this JavaScript needs to work with the rendered elements from the DOM.

According to Google the `OnAfterRenderAsync` method should be the key to go but I don't know how I should do it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

As per my guess, you need to add those *.js file references in index.html file. 
And if there is any particular method that you want to execute after page render then you can use the JavaScript interop.

**Index.html**

```
<script>
  window.yourMethodName = (paraName) => {
    // ...
    // return something;
  };
</script>
```

**Component.razor**

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;
//...
private async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync()
{
    var something = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("convertArrayyourMethodName", paraName);
}
```